# Mapping vector pointers of different type

Tags: c++, mapping, stdvector

Assuming that I want to have some vectors that each contain objects of a different type, 
is there any way to map the pointers to them ?
Something like this:

```
std::vector<class1> vec1;
std::vector<class2> vec2;
std::vector<class3> vec3;

mapper.addVectorPtr(&vec1);
mapper.addVectorPtr(&vec2);
mapper.addVectorPtr(&vec3);

std::vector<class1> * ptr1 = mapper.getVectorPtr<class1>;
std::vector<class2> * ptr2 = mapper.getVectorPtr<class2>;
std::vector<class3> * ptr3 = mapper.getVectorPtr<class3>;
```

I could probably use a custom class with a vector pointer as a member, which would derive from a common base class. Then I coudld downcast them to the desired class and retrieve the pointer but I would like to to see if there are some better options.

Comment: Do you know the class1... class N at compile time ? Or are you looking for a fully generic solution ?

Comment: @quantdev Can you elaborate a bit? It should work for any class if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should checkout http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/ . You can get typeinfo this way. Allowing you to create a map with an integer (=the hashcode) as key.

you can then implement your mapclass as follows (requires a constructor without arguments)

```
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class typemap{
    std::map<unsigned long, void*> m_ptrs;
public:
    template<typename A>
    void addVectorPtr(std::vector<A>* b){
        A a;
        m_ptrs[ typeid(a).hash_code() ] = b;
    }

    template<typename A>
    std::vector<A>* getVectorPtr(){
        A a;//this is why you need the default constructor
        return (std::vector<A>*) (m_ptrs[ typeid(a).hash_code() ]);
    }
};


int main(){
    std::vector<int>* t1 = new std::vector<int>(3,3);
    typemap tm;
    tm.addVectorPtr(t1);

    std::vector<int> v=*(tm.getVectorPtr<int>());

    for(auto it = v.begin(); it!= v.end(); ++it){
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. I would use type_index for mapping but for some reason casting from void* did not occur to me at all!

Comment: @Veritas I'm actually trying it to get to work here, but I don't seem to be able to. There are certainly many mistakes in this example

Comment: There may be, I didn't check. It's the approach that I like.

Comment: I was wondering, what if we replaced addVectorPtr with an addVector template function that would create a vector and store it internally in the mapper? The getVectorPtr would get replaced with a getVector template function that would return a reference to the wanted vector. Would I have to follow my original solution and make a custom base class and derived class with std::vector as it's member and then cast as necessary and retrieve the vector afterwards, or is there a better solution?

Comment: If I understand correctly, things would become quite more difficult. The implementation of what you want is easy: just define addVector() so that it calls "addVectorPtr(new std::vector<type>);" and implement addVector like so: " return getVectorPtr() ". The real difficulty would be to write the destructor, I don't see yet how you would do that without having a basetype, as you can't delete a void-pointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55874/discussion-between-pinna-be-and-veritas).